Why do i keep getting this error nvcr.io/nvidia/tao/tao-toolkit-tf, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'?
I am completing the NVIDIA Disaster Risk Monitoring Using Satellite Imagery course which uses the TAO toolkit.
I have an NVIDIA NGC API Key and everything works fine when I login to dockers with it. But when I run the dockers container for training a deep learning model I keep getting this error:
Pulling from repository: nvcr.io/nvidia/tao/tao-toolkit-tf
Docker pull failed. 404 Client Error: Not Found ("pull access denied for nvcr.io/nvidia/tao/tao-toolkit-tf, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied")
I'm confused because I see a Login Succeeded.
I have tried generating other api keys and searching the internet for anyone else facing this problem, but to no avail.
